# Copy rows to Cumulative workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to loop through my sheets, and exclude certain ones (shown below). Each month this code with be run, it need to copy all the data for that month into the cumulative file. Defined by the WhatFor Value.

If it is the first month that the code is being run, it needs to copy all the historic data along with that month.

The code I have below create the cumulative document is it does not exist, and the copies the data for that month. If I then go to run the code again it breaks at `wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues`

I cannot seem to get it to loop through all rows, sheets and copy all data if it is the first month.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim MyPath As String: MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Dim myData As Workbook, wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim WhatFor As String, sheet As Worksheet, FirstAddress As String, cell As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    WhatFor = ThisWorkbook.sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("L9")

    If Dir(MyPath & "\Cumulative.xls") = "" Then
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Workbooks.Add
        Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
        wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        With wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1").Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
        With wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Columns("I:L")
            .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
        End With
        With wbNew.sheets("Sheet1")
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Payment No#"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = "WO No#"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1") = "Address"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1") = "Discription"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1") = "Discription2"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("F1") = "Discription3"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("G1") = "Discription5"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("H1") = "Discription5"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("I1") = "Labout Costs"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("J1") = "Total Claimed"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1") = "Costs Omitted"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("L1") = "Costs Certified"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1") = "Type of Work"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = "S/C's App Notes / Notes"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("O1") = "Paid Under"
            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1").Columns.AutoFit
        End With
        wbNew.sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Delete

        For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.sheets
`exclude these ->`  If sheet.Name <> "PAYMENT FORM" And sheet.Name <> "Global" And sheet.Name <> "MergedData" And sheet.Name <> "Details" And sheet.Name <> "Template" Then
                With sheet.Columns(1)
                    Set cell = .Find(what:= **<0**, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                        FirstAddress = cell.Address
                        Do
                            sheet.Columns("O:R").ClearContents
                            cell.EntireRow.Copy
                            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
                            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = sheet.Name
                            Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
                        Loop Until cell Is Nothing Or cell.Address = FirstAddress
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next sheet
        wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\Cumulative.xls", FileFormat:=56
        wbNew.Close
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set myData = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\Cululative.xls")
        DoEvents
        For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.sheets
            If sheet.Name <> "PAYMENT FORM" And sheet.Name <> "Global" And sheet.Name <> "MergedData" And sheet.Name <> "Details" And sheet.Name <> "Template" Then
                With sheet.Columns(1)
                    Set cell = .Find(WhatFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                        FirstAddress = cell.Address
                        Do
                            sheet.Columns("O:R").ClearContents
                            cell.EntireRow.Copy
                            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
                            wbNew.sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = sheet.Name
                            Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
                        Loop Until cell Is Nothing Or cell.Address = FirstAddress
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next sheet
        myData.Save
        myData.Close
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: If you really want to increase the chances of someone assisting you with this issue, I suggest to share the file so we don't need to guess trying to replicate the data and the problem as well as it'll save us a lot of typing. If the data is confidential, just share a mirror file with random data, ensure the structure remains the same and that the data types are the same and the samples relevant to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't the whole answer you're after.  I've tidied up your code, changed a couple of things that could be done easier and maybe helped with your actual problem?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim myData As Workbook, wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim WhatFor As String, sheet As Worksheet, FirstAddress As String, cell As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'You've defined ThisWorkbook here - so use it throughtout the procedure.
    MyPath = wb.Path

    WhatFor = wb.Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Range("L9").Value 'Be explicit - you want the value.

    If Dir(MyPath & "\Cumulative.xls") = "" Then
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'Create a book with 1 sheet.

        With wbNew.Sheets(1)
            With .Range("A1:O1")
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                With .Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                End With
            End With
            With .Columns("I:L")
                .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            End With
            .Range("A1:O1") = Array("Payment No#", "WO No#", "Address", "Discription", "Discription2", _
                "Discription3", "Discription5", "Discription5", "Labout Costs", "Total Claimed", _
                "Costs Omitted", "Costs Certified", "Type of Work", "S/C's App Notes / Notes", _
                "Paid Under")
            .Range("A1:O1").Columns.AutoFit
        End With

        For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
            Select Case sheet.Name
                Case "PAYMENT FORM", "Global", "MergedData", "Details", "Template"
                    'These sheets are excluded, so do nothing?
                    'If you want to do something - put your code here.
                Case Else
                    With sheet.Columns(1)
                        Set cell = .Find(What:=1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                        If Not cell Is Nothing Then
                            sheet.Columns("O:R").ClearContents
                            FirstAddress = cell.Address
                            Do
                                cell.EntireRow.Copy
                                wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues
                                wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sheet.Name
                                Set cell = .FindNext(cell)
                            Loop Until cell Is Nothing Or cell.Address = FirstAddress
                        End If
                    End With
                    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\Cumulative.xls", FileFormat:=56
                    wbNew.Close
            End Select
        Next sheet
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have updated my OP which hopefully explains the situation more.